# Is there a way to slow down a BackgroundWorker in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

In some games, there is a splash screen that downloads content from a server. It might give some tips while you're waiting. I'm doing something similar, only that the loading happens really quick, but I want it to wait a few more seconds.

When the user first loads my application, it has a screen with a progress bar. At the moment, it checks if the server is online. If it is, it says "Connected!" However, it immediately fades out my controls. I want it to wait about 5 more seconds so the reader can read it. Then fade the controls out.

```
    private void frmMain_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        // Start background worker
        m_bgWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        m_bgWorker.ProgressChanged += M_bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
        m_bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        m_bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
        m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(100); 
    } 


    private void M_bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progConnect.Value = 0; 

        if (SystemBO.IsOnline())
        {
            lblConnection.Content = "Connected!"; 
        }

        progConnect.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        // TODO: Wait 5 seconds here...

        // Fade out controls
        lblTitle.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);
        progConnect.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);
        lblConnection.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);
    }
```

Note:

- I tried `System.Sleep()`, but that made no difference. I understand why. The idea is the same though: I want the background worker to sleep for 5 seconds before completing.

**Solution:**

I added a few more events: DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted.

Then I added this code:

```
    private void M_bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        { 
                m_index++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
                m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(m_index);
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);  // wait 3 seconds to read 
    }
```

It worked. The progress bar animates quite smoothly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

rather than the last line in frmMain_Loaded:

```
m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(100);
```

I would put a for loop with Sleep(), for simulating some extra processing:

```
for (int i=0; i<=100; i+=10)
{
    if (SystemBO.IsOnline())
        i = 100;
    Sleep(1000);
    m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

Comment: Using `Thread.Sleep` is almost always a bad idea. `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));` would be much better.

Comment: @Enigmativity:I tried that, but got this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.'

Comment: @Bob - Sounds like you're reusing a `Task.Delay`. Can you show the code?

Comment: @Bob - In any case `Sleep` is not the answer.

Comment: Suggesting an async operation for a task which is *intentionally* delayed is just a fanatic response. Async is not the answer to everything. Sleep works well for this specific use-case, as there isn't anything else to do while the progress dialog is shown. If there is a user action to do (unusual), the UI will still respond after 1 second, or even less, if you change the sleep duration.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do the fade-out in the [`ProgressChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) handler. That handler really should only be used to update progress information like text and a percentage bar.

Your fade-out logic should be moved to the separate [`RunWorkedCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler. Here you can let the thread sleep/await a scheduled task for a while before beginning to fade out the controls. (Using `async`/`await` over `Thread.Sleep()` here has the advantage of not blocking the UI thread while waiting, so the UI still remains responsive while waiting for the time to pass.)

It also ensures that the code is called at the very end and not every time the worker reports any kind of progress. And it's also cleaner because it allows you to handle different termination states by checking the `RunWorkedCompletedEventArgs`:

- If `e.Error` is set, an exception occurred in the worker thread.
- If `e.Cancelled` is true, the worker thread got cancelled by calling `CancelAsync()` on the worker. (Only possible if `WorkerSupportsCancellation` is set to `true` and only useful if code in the [`DoWork`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx) handler actually checks for the cancellation flag)
- Otherwise everything went okay.

---

Side note:

I am assuming that your code is not a full example, because you have no actual handler assigned to the `DoWork` event. So right now it would not do anything. And calling `ReportProgress()` right from the main thread is wrong as well. That method is designed to be called from within the `DoWork` event handling method in order to let the asynchronous thread report status updates back to the UI, since those events are handled on the main thread.

Comment: I noticed BackgroundWorker has some additional events, so I tried those out. Worked much better, yes!

Comment: On a related note, if you are on .NET 4.5 or above, you might want to look into doing the whole thing with `Task.Run` instead of the `BackgroundWorker`. It just seems like a more modern and straight-forward approach that avoids the hassle with all the different event handlers: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

Comment: I believe I tried Task, but with it running on a separate thread, it couldn't access the control because the main thread had control of it. It was a bit of a pain, and then I came across BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Bob that is what the Dispatcher is used for.  Dispatcher.Invoke will run the function on the UI thread

Comment: See the 5th point of the link I posted. To report progress with a task, you can instantiate a `Progress` object with a delegate function, which is called when you call the `Report()` method on the object. The benefit over the background worker is that the reported object can by any type, rather than just an integer and string.